# CGAffineTransformationMake behaves oddly for iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

**Regarding:** iOS 5 & 6. CGAffineTransformationMake

**What I have:** one UILabel and one UIImage

**What I want to do:** I am trying to create a flipping card. When I tap on UIImage, it should flip horizontally and hide and the UILabel should appear. Almost like flipping horizontally a baseball card, with image on front and text on back. And when you tap on UILabel, it flips same way to show the UIImage.

**What's the problem:** My code behaves perfectly for iOS 6 but the transformation appears weird on iOS 5. On iOS 6, the image flips horizontally to hide itself and show the text. Tapping on uilabel flips the text to hide it and show the image. Works like a charm. But when I run this on iOS 5, on tapping on the image, the text appears with a 180 degree rotation from the bottom of the screen, with a spiraling motion.

I don't want to use `UIView transitionFromView: toView: duration: options: completion:^(bool)` simply because there are some other unrelated issues associated with it which is a discussion for another thread.

**Details with Code Snippets:**
My UILabel initially has the following transformation:

```
self.myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Tapping on UIImage or UILabel calls the following method

```
- (IBAction)flipImage:(id)sender {

    if(flipped == 0) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                        animations:^{

                             self.myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                             self.myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

                             flipped = 1;
                          } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 NSLog(@"Flipped!");
                          }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                             self.myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                             flipped = 0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"Flipped!");
                         }];
      }
}
```

Any help?